# Calling closure on different object?

Tags: groovy, functional-programming, closures

Suppose I have this class:

```
class MyClass {
    int myInt

    MyClass(myInt) {
        this.myInt = myInt
    }

    def myMethod() {
        print this.myInt
    }
}
```

And somewhere I have:

```
def myClass1 = new MyClass(1)
def myMethodClosure = myClass1.&myMethod
def myClass2 = new MyClass(2)
```

Now if I call `myMethodClosure()` it will call `myMethod()` on `myClass1` instance which will print 1. What I want is to call the same `myMethodClosure` but on a different instance, in this case on `myClass2` so it can print 2. Is this possible?

I have tried using `setDelegate()`, but it does not work. I have also seen that there is field `thisObject` inside the closure class, but it does not have a setter, only a getter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There were two methods added to Groovy to aid serialization of Closures, `dehydrate` and `rehydrate`. Basically, they strip (and reconstruct) a Closure's `owner`, `thisObject` and `delegate`.  In this example, you *could* do:

```
myMethodClosure.rehydrate( myClass2, myClass2, myClass2 )()
```

To get the output `2`, however I'd be wary about doing this as it is not what the method was intended for and there could be serious unforeseen consequences.

A better solution would probably be to write a factory method that gets a method reference for the given instance of `MyClass`. There may be other -- better -- solutions, but it depends on the situation you are in (that I suspect is not shown by the example in the question)

Answer (score 2):

I believe closure "includes" the enclosing object to act upon. It is not possible override "this" inside a closure at runtime.

Comment: +1 `myMethodClosure` is a closure which just calls that method on the `owner` of the Closure. And there are no public setters for owner.

Comment: Although you can do this: `myMethodClosure.rehydrate( myClass2, myClass2, myClass2 )()` Though it can't be recommended as it's an obvious hack ;-)