# Substitute 'this' invoking a method reference in Groovy

Tags: groovy, closures

Invoking a non-static method reference is easy when the reference is obtained from an instance:

```
class Foo { void funk() { println "okay!" } }
Foo foo = new Foo()
Closure closure = foo.&funk
closure() // okay! is printed
```

But how to substitite `this` when the method reference is obtained from a class?

```
class Foo { void funk() { println "okay!" } }
Foo foo = new Foo()
Closure closure = Foo.&funk
// closure.delegate = foo // not helpful
closure()
// => java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
```

Comment: +1, especially because you just introduced me to the `.&` operator!

Comment: However, this sounds a lot like a duplicate of [Calling closure on different object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765021/calling-closure-on-different-object), which is basically claiming that this isn't possible.

Answer (score 3):

The following solves your problem:

```
class Foo { void funk() { println "okay!" } }
Closure closure = { Foo.&funk.rehydrate(delegate, it, it).call() }
Foo foo = new Foo()
closure(foo)
```